# Cannot access object property. Typescript with multer

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm, multer, multer-s3

I am facing an issue, or lack of skill problem that is:

I'm trying to upload an image into my application and trying to storage it in AWS S3. Bucket and IAM user were created with success, I'm able to store the artifact there, but when I try to save some property of "file" object in my database is where this issue shows up.

I can read this property in "console.log, console.info", either using Object.keys(requestedFile), or JSON.stringify(requestedFile). But VSCode intelisense cannot read, eveything turns red, this code cannot be compiled, etc...

Let me show, and try to explain how I'm doing:

This is the route I am calling to execute this service:

```
routes.post("/test/upload", multerConfig.single('file'), createAttachment.handle);
```

multerConfig.ts

```
import multer from "multer";
import { limits } from "./FileLimits";
import { dest } from "./LocalDestination";
import { storageTypes } from "./StorageTypes";

export const multerConfig = multer({
    storage: storageTypes["s3"],
    dest: dest,
    limits: limits,  
});
```

./storageTypes.ts

```
import multer from "multer";
import path from "path";
import crypto from "crypto";
import multerS3 from "multer-s3"
import aws from "aws-sdk";

const fileResolvePath = __dirname +  "../../tmp/uploads";
const dest = path.resolve(fileResolvePath)

// Here I've placed local and S3 storage types, local is only for dev purposes.

export const storageTypes = {
    local: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, dest)
        },
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
            crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, hash) => {
                if(err) {
                    cb(err, err.message)
                } else {
                const fileName = `${hash.toString('hex')}-${file.originalname}`;
                cb(null, fileName);
                }
            })}
    }),
    s3 : multerS3({
        s3: new aws.S3(),
        bucket: "bucket-name", 
        contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
        acl: 'public-read',
        key:  (req, file, cb) => {
            crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, hash) => {
                if(err){
                    cb(err, err.message)
                }else{
                    const fileName = `${hash.toString('hex')}-${file.originalname}`;
                    return cb(null, fileName);
                }
            })
        }})
        
}
```

Ok, now whenever I try to access some req.file properties all other properties (that were added to this object) is not accessible.

console.log(req.file):

```
{
  "fieldname": "file",
  "originalname": "profile_03.PNG",
  "encoding": "7bit",
  "mimetype": "image/png",
  "size": 158935,
  "bucket": "bucket-name",
  "key": "17378cbe3e20f6ceabe274af8ca5d96e-profile_03.PNG",
  "acl": "public-read",
  "contentType": "image/png",
  "contentDisposition": null,
  "contentEncoding": null,
  "storageClass": "STANDARD",
  "serverSideEncryption": null,
  "metadata": null,
  "location": "https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/17378cb123uns1be274af8ca5d96e-perfil_03.PNG",
  "etag": "\"4fd89662891jsdu38jsdjnqr9cd\"",
  "versionId": "_tB2adfWDF49s2Fijfaoi3sW5"
}
```

output of Object.Keys(requestedFile):

```
ObjectKeys: {
    objectKeys: [
      'fieldname',            'originalname',
      'encoding',             'mimetype',
      'size',                 'bucket',
      'key',                  'acl',
      'contentType',          'contentDisposition',
      'contentEncoding',      'storageClass',
      'serverSideEncryption', 'metadata',
      'location',             'etag',
      'versionId'
    ]
  },
```

and this is my Controller / Service class:

```
export class CreateAttachmentController {
    async handle ( req: Request, res: Response ){
        try {
            const {
                // this is where I try to access .key, or .location properties.
            } = req.file;
        const attachmentRepository = getCustomRepository(AttachmentRepository);
        const attachment = await attachmentRepository.create({
            // this is where I try to save this to database
        });

        await attachmentRepository.save(attachment);

        return res.json(attachment);
    }
}};
```

Conclusion, I don't know if I am doing something wrong, if I should use Promises, or this is the expected behavior and something that is not working as properly in this code. By the way tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true   
}
```

Well, this is eveything I got for now, if someone finds out what's happening, I'd be apreciated.

Thanks in advance,

dribeiroferr

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of research I found out that **multer-s3** does not provide an native support types for VsCode, that makes visual studio intellisense see what it is inside that object yet.

This is what I did:

Created an exported interface:

```
import express from "express";

export interface IMulterRequestFile {
    key: string
    path: string
    mimetype: string
    originalname: string
    size: number
    location: string
  }
```

Then, into my **Controller.ts**:

```
export class Controller {
    async handle (req: Request & { file: MulterFile }, res: Response){ 
}
```

And voalá, now I am reaching out all the properties I want to access that **multer-S3** has inserted into file object. Actually, this is not an elegant way to do that, but it works ! (:

ps: I don't know if they will raise a PR to fix this in the future.